# Parshas Korach: Why does the Torah say Moshe got very angry, and Rashi translates it as Moshe got very distressed or pained

Tags: rashi, parshat-korach

In Parshas Korach ([Bamidbar 16:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.15?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.16.15.1&lang2=bi)), the Torah says ויחר למשה מאוד. Rashi translates it as Moshe was distresed a lot. Rashi doesnt say Moshe was very angry.

Why doesnt Rashi translate it the way the verse wrote it? What did Rashi gain by saying Moshe was distressed a lot instead of very angry?  If Rashi feels the verse means Moshe was very distressed why didnt the verse use a different word instead of ויחר?

Comment: Why do you assume that vayechar means "got angry"? Its first use (Bereishit 4:5) means "distressed" also. Maybe without "af" it doesn't mean angry.

Comment: Well answered. However why in Parshas Korach does Rashi wait to translate Vayichar Limoshe as Moshe got distressed a lot, it should have translated Vayichar Likyain Miod in Breishes in that Passuk as Kayin got distressed a lot?

Comment: Maybe he was acknowledging the hava amina that in this case (but not by Kayin) one might have thought it meant anger.